# How to write a type with optional unknown property name but known property type together with named and typed properties

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write something like this. It's been simplified for clarity:

```
    interface $ {
        frameWorkMethod<T>(first: T, options: FrameworkMethodOptions<T>): object;
    }

    interface FrameworkMethodOptions<T> {
        aProperty?: string[];
        anotherProperty?: boolean;
        [P in keyof T]?: OptionsCallBack //THIS GIVES ERROR
    }

    interface OptionsCallBack {
        create?: () => void;
        update?: () => void;
    }
```

The idea is a valid `FrameworkMethodOptions<T>` can be:

1. an empty object { } i.e. no properties,
2. have one or more of the properties.
3. undefined / unknown named properties (the third property in the above interface) must have the name of a property of T ( P in keyof T).

Examples of valid objects:

```
var user: User = { name: "leonardo", age: 33 };

interface User {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}

var example1: FrameworkMethodOptions<any> = {
    aProperty: ["this is string", " ignoreThis"]
};

var example2: FrameworkMethodOptions<any> = {
    aProperty: ["this is string", " ignoreThis"],
    age: { create: () => { console.log("ah") } }
};

var example3: FrameworkMethodOptions<User> = {
    aProperty: ["this is string", " ignoreThis"],
    age: { create: () => { console.log("ah") } }
};

var example4: FrameworkMethodOptions<User> = {
    aProperty: ["this is string", " ignoreThis"],
};

var example5: FrameworkMethodOptions<User> = {
    age: { create: () => { console.log("ah") } }
};

var example6: FrameworkMethodOptions<User> = {};
var example7: FrameworkMethodOptions<any> = {};
```

You can see the errors, other alternatives I tried and work on the code in [this Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20FrameworkMethodOptions%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20aProperty%3F%3A%20string%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20anotherProperty%3F%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BP%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3F%3A%20OptionsCallBack%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20OptionsCallBack%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20create%3F%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20update%3F%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20user%3A%20User%20%3D%20%7B%20name%3A%20%22leonardo%22%2C%20age%3A%2033%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20User%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20age%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20example1%3A%20FrameworkMethodOptions%3Cany%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20aProperty%3A%20%5B%22this%20is%20string%22%2C%20%22%20ignoreThis%22%5D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20example2%3A%20FrameworkMethodOptions%3Cany%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20aProperty%3A%20%5B%22this%20is%20string%22%2C%20%22%20ignoreThis%22%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20age%3A%20%7B%20create%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20console.log(%22ah%22)%20%7D%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20example3%3A%20FrameworkMethodOptions%3CUser%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20aProperty%3A%20%5B%22this%20is%20string%22%2C%20%22%20ignoreThis%22%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20age%3A%20%7B%20create%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20console.log(%22ah%22)%20%7D%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20example4%3A%20FrameworkMethodOptions%3CUser%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20aProperty%3A%20%5B%22this%20is%20string%22%2C%20%22%20ignoreThis%22%5D%2C%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20example5%3A%20FrameworkMethodOptions%3CUser%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20age%3A%20%7B%20create%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20console.log(%22ah%22)%20%7D%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20example6%3A%20FrameworkMethodOptions%3CUser%3E%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0Avar%20example7%3A%20FrameworkMethodOptions%3Cany%3E%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%0D%0A%2F%2FB%20Alternative%20Idea%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20FrameworkMethodOptionsPart1%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20aProperty%3F%3A%20string%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20anotherProperty%3F%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20FrameworkMethodOptionsPart2%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BP%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3F%3A%20OptionsCallBack%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20FrameworkMethodOptionsMultiPart%3CT%3E%20%3D%20FrameworkMethodOptionsPart1%20%26%20FrameworkMethodOptionsPart2%3CT%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20example1b%3A%20FrameworkMethodOptionsMultiPart%3Cany%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20aProperty%3A%20%5B%22this%20is%20string%22%2C%20%22%20ignoreThis%22%5D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20example2b%3A%20FrameworkMethodOptionsMultiPart%3Cany%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20aProperty%3A%20%5B%22this%20is%20string%22%2C%20%22%20ignoreThis%22%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20age%3A%20%7B%20create%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20console.log(%22ah%22)%20%7D%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20example3b%3A%20FrameworkMethodOptionsMultiPart%3CUser%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20aProperty%3A%20%5B%22this%20is%20string%22%2C%20%22%20ignoreThis%22%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20age%3A%20%7B%20create%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20console.log(%22ah%22)%20%7D%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20example4b%3A%20FrameworkMethodOptionsMultiPart%3CUser%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20aProperty%3A%20%5B%22this%20is%20string%22%2C%20%22%20ignoreThis%22%5D%2C%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20example5b%3A%20FrameworkMethodOptionsMultiPart%3CUser%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20age%3A%20%7B%20create%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20console.log(%22ah%22)%20%7D%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20example6b%3A%20FrameworkMethodOptionsMultiPart%3CUser%3E%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0Avar%20example7b%3A%20FrameworkMethodOptionsMultiPart%3Cany%3E%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%0D%0A%2F%2F%20C%20Alterntive%20Idea%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20FrameworkMethodOptionsConditional%3CT%3E%20%3D%20any%20extends%20T%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3F%20FrameworkMethodOptionsPart1%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3A%20FrameworkMethodOptionsPart1%20%26%20FrameworkMethodOptionsPart2%3CT%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20example1c%3A%20FrameworkMethodOptionsConditional%3Cany%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20aProperty%3A%20%5B%22this%20is%20string%22%2C%20%22%20ignoreThis%22%5D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20example2c%3A%20FrameworkMethodOptionsConditional%3Cany%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20aProperty%3A%20%5B%22this%20is%20string%22%2C%20%22%20ignoreThis%22%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20age%3A%20%7B%20create%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20console.log(%22ah%22)%20%7D%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20example3c%3A%20FrameworkMethodOptionsConditional%3CUser%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20aProperty%3A%20%5B%22this%20is%20string%22%2C%20%22%20ignoreThis%22%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20age%3A%20%7B%20create%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20console.log(%22ah%22)%20%7D%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20example4c%3A%20FrameworkMethodOptionsConditional%3CUser%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20aProperty%3A%20%5B%22this%20is%20string%22%2C%20%22%20ignoreThis%22%5D%2C%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20example5c%3A%20FrameworkMethodOptionsConditional%3CUser%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20age%3A%20%7B%20create%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20console.log(%22ah%22)%20%7D%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20example6c%3A%20FrameworkMethodOptionsConditional%3CUser%3E%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0Avar%20example7c%3A%20FrameworkMethodOptionsConditional%3Cany%3E%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%0D%0A%2F%2F%20D%20Alterntive%20Idea%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20FrameworkMethodOptionsPart1%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20aProperty%3F%3A%20string%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20anotherProperty%3F%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20FrameworkMethodOptionsPart2Typed%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BP%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3F%3A%20OptionsCallBack%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20FrameworkMethodOptionsPart2Untyped%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20OptionsCallBack%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20TS%20DOESNT%20ALLOW%20THIS%20TO%20BE%20OPTIONAL%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20FrameworkMethodOptionsComplex%3CT%3E%20%3D%20any%20extends%20T%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3F%20FrameworkMethodOptionsPart1%20%26%20FrameworkMethodOptionsPart2Untyped%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3A%20FrameworkMethodOptionsPart1%20%26%20FrameworkMethodOptionsPart2%3CT%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20example1d%3A%20FrameworkMethodOptionsComplex%3Cany%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20aProperty%3A%20%5B%22this%20is%20string%22%2C%20%22%20ignoreThis%22%5D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20example2d%3A%20FrameworkMethodOptionsComplex%3Cany%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20aProperty%3A%20%5B%22this%20is%20string%22%2C%20%22%20ignoreThis%22%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20age%3A%20%7B%20create%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20console.log(%22ah%22)%20%7D%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20example3d%3A%20FrameworkMethodOptionsComplex%3CUser%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20aProperty%3A%20%5B%22this%20is%20string%22%2C%20%22%20ignoreThis%22%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20age%3A%20%7B%20create%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20console.log(%22ah%22)%20%7D%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20example4d%3A%20FrameworkMethodOptionsComplex%3CUser%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20aProperty%3A%20%5B%22this%20is%20string%22%2C%20%22%20ignoreThis%22%5D%2C%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20example5d%3A%20FrameworkMethodOptionsComplex%3CUser%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20age%3A%20%7B%20create%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20console.log(%22ah%22)%20%7D%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20example6d%3A%20FrameworkMethodOptionsComplex%3CUser%3E%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0Avar%20example7d%3A%20FrameworkMethodOptionsComplex%3Cany%3E%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B)

There is a catch: I'm using TS 2.3. But but even with the latest TS version, I'm don't think it's possible.
Backstory: Knockout Mapping is a pluging for KnockoutJS. I'm trying to improve the typescript typing of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me

```
interface FrameworkMethodOptionsPart1 {
    aProperty?: string[];
    anotherProperty?: boolean;
}
type FrameworkMethodOptionsPart2<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: OptionsCallBack
}    
type FrameworkMethodOptions<T> = FrameworkMethodOptionsPart1 | FrameworkMethodOptionsPart2<T>;
```

For future reference porpuses, bellow are all the alternatives I tried, in case the Playground Link stops working.

YOU NEED TO  copy and paste the code in a typescript enabled ide / code editor to see the errors.

```
//imagine this is the framework declarations
interface $ {
    frameWorkMethod<T>(first: T, options: FrameworkMethodOptions<T>): object;
}

interface FrameworkMethodOptions<T> {
    aProperty?: string[];
    anotherProperty?: boolean;
    [P in keyof T]?: OptionsCallBack;
}

interface OptionsCallBack {
    create?: () => void;
    update?: () => void;
}

var user: User = { name: "leonardo", age: 33 };

interface User {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}

var example1: FrameworkMethodOptions<any> = {
    aProperty: ["this is string", " ignoreThis"]
};

var example2: FrameworkMethodOptions<any> = {
    aProperty: ["this is string", " ignoreThis"],
    address: { create: () => { console.log("ah") } }
};

var example3: FrameworkMethodOptions<User> = {
    aProperty: ["this is string", " ignoreThis"],
    age: { create: () => { console.log("ah") } }
};

var example4: FrameworkMethodOptions<User> = {
    aProperty: ["this is string", " ignoreThis"],
};

var example5: FrameworkMethodOptions<User> = {
    age: { create: () => { console.log("ah") } }
};

var example6: FrameworkMethodOptions<User> = {};
var example7: FrameworkMethodOptions<any> = {};

var invalidExample1: FrameworkMethodOptions<User> = {
    address: { create: () => { console.log("ah") } } //Address ist not part of User interface
};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//B Alternative Idea

interface FrameworkMethodOptionsPart1 {
    aProperty?: string[];
    anotherProperty?: boolean;
}

type FrameworkMethodOptionsPart2<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: OptionsCallBack
}

type FrameworkMethodOptionsB<T> = FrameworkMethodOptionsPart1 & FrameworkMethodOptionsPart2<T>;

var example1b: FrameworkMethodOptionsB<any> = {
    aProperty: ["this is string", " ignoreThis"]
};

var example2b: FrameworkMethodOptionsB<any> = {
    aProperty: ["this is string", " ignoreThis"],
    address: { create: () => { console.log("ah") } }
};

var example3b: FrameworkMethodOptionsB<User> = {
    aProperty: ["this is string", " ignoreThis"],
    age: { create: () => { console.log("ah") } }
};

var example4b: FrameworkMethodOptionsB<User> = {
    aProperty: ["this is string", " ignoreThis"],
};

var example5b: FrameworkMethodOptionsB<User> = {
    age: { create: () => { console.log("ah") } }
};

var example6b: FrameworkMethodOptionsB<User> = {};
var example7b: FrameworkMethodOptionsB<any> = {};

var invalidExample1b: FrameworkMethodOptionsB<User> = {
    address: { create: () => { console.log("ah") } } //Address is not part of User interface
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// C Alternative Idea

type FrameworkMethodOptionsC<T> = any extends T
    ? FrameworkMethodOptionsPart1
    : FrameworkMethodOptionsPart1 & FrameworkMethodOptionsPart2<T>;


var example1c: FrameworkMethodOptionsC<any> = {
    aProperty: ["this is string", " ignoreThis"]
};

var example2c: FrameworkMethodOptionsC<any> = {
    aProperty: ["this is string", " ignoreThis"],
    address: { create: () => { console.log("ah") } }
};

var example3c: FrameworkMethodOptionsC<User> = {
    aProperty: ["this is string", " ignoreThis"],
    age: { create: () => { console.log("ah") } }
};

var example4c: FrameworkMethodOptionsC<User> = {
    aProperty: ["this is string", " ignoreThis"],
};

var example5c: FrameworkMethodOptionsC<User> = {
    age: { create: () => { console.log("ah") } }
};

var example6c: FrameworkMethodOptionsC<User> = {};
var example7c: FrameworkMethodOptionsC<any> = {};

var invalidExample1c: FrameworkMethodOptionsC<User> = {
    address: { create: () => { console.log("ah") } } //Address is not part of User interface
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// D Alternative Idea

type FrameworkMethodOptionsPart2Untyped = {
    [key: string]: OptionsCallBack     // TS DOESNT ALLOW THIS TO BE OPTIONAL
}

type FrameworkMethodOptionsD<T> = any extends T
    ? FrameworkMethodOptionsPart1 & FrameworkMethodOptionsPart2Untyped
    : FrameworkMethodOptionsPart1 & FrameworkMethodOptionsPart2<T>;

var example1d: FrameworkMethodOptionsD<any> = {
    aProperty: ["this is string", " ignoreThis"]
};

var example2d: FrameworkMethodOptionsD<any> = {
    aProperty: ["this is string", " ignoreThis"],
    address: { create: () => { console.log("ah") } }
};

var example3d: FrameworkMethodOptionsD<User> = {
    aProperty: ["this is string", " ignoreThis"],
    age: { create: () => { console.log("ah") } }
};

var example4d: FrameworkMethodOptionsD<User> = {
    aProperty: ["this is string", " ignoreThis"],
};

var example5d: FrameworkMethodOptionsD<User> = {
    age: { create: () => { console.log("ah") } }
};

var example6d: FrameworkMethodOptionsD<User> = {};
var example7d: FrameworkMethodOptionsD<any> = {};

var invalidExample1d: FrameworkMethodOptionsD<User> = {
    address: { create: () => { console.log("ah") } } //Address is not part of User interface
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// E Alternative Idea

type FrameworkMethodOptionsE<T> = FrameworkMethodOptionsPart1 & FrameworkMethodOptionsPart2Untyped

var example1e: FrameworkMethodOptionsE<any> = {
    aProperty: ["this is string", " ignoreThis"]
};

var example2e: FrameworkMethodOptionsE<any> = {
    aProperty: ["this is string", " ignoreThis"],
    address: { create: () => { console.log("ah") } }
};

var example3e: FrameworkMethodOptionsE<User> = {
    aProperty: ["this is string", " ignoreThis"],
    age: { create: () => { console.log("ah") } }
};

var example4e: FrameworkMethodOptionsE<User> = {
    aProperty: ["this is string", " ignoreThis"],
};

var example5e: FrameworkMethodOptionsE<User> = {
    age: { create: () => { console.log("ah") } }
};

var example6e: FrameworkMethodOptionsE<User> = {};
var example7e: FrameworkMethodOptionsE<any> = {};

var invalidExample1e: FrameworkMethodOptionsE<User> = {
    address: { create: () => { console.log("ah") } } //Address is not part of User interface
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// F Alternative Idea. THIS ONE WORKS. !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

type FrameworkMethodOptionsF<T> = FrameworkMethodOptionsPart1 | FrameworkMethodOptionsPart2<T>;

var example1f: FrameworkMethodOptionsF<any> = {
    aProperty: ["this is string", " ignoreThis"]
};

var example2f: FrameworkMethodOptionsF<any> = {
    aProperty: ["this is string", " ignoreThis"],
    address: { create: () => { console.log("ah") } },
    anythingGoes: 42
};

var example3f: FrameworkMethodOptionsF<User> = {
    aProperty: ["this is string", " ignoreThis"],
    age: { create: () => { console.log("ah") } }
};

var example4f: FrameworkMethodOptionsF<User> = {
    aProperty: ["this is string", " ignoreThis"],
};

var example5f: FrameworkMethodOptionsF<User> = {
    age: { create: () => { console.log("ah") } }
};

var example6f: FrameworkMethodOptionsF<User> = {};
var example7f: FrameworkMethodOptionsF<any> = {};

var invalidExample1f: FrameworkMethodOptionsF<User> = {
    address: { create: () => { console.log("ah") } } //Expect error. Address is not part of User interface
};

var invalidExample2f: FrameworkMethodOptionsF<User> = {
    age: { create: () => { console.log("ah") } },
    address: { create: () => { console.log("ah") } } //Expect error. Address is not part of User interface
};

var invalidExample3f: FrameworkMethodOptionsF<User> = {
    aProperty: ["this is string", " ignoreThis"],
    address: { create: () => { console.log("ah") } } //Expect error. Address is not part of User interface
};

var invalidExample4f: FrameworkMethodOptionsF<User> = {
    aProperty: 42, //Expect error. aProperty's type is  string[]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, enjoy.

If there are any problems let me know.

```
type FrameworkMethodOptions2<T> = any extends T
    ? FrameworkMethodOptionsPart1
    : FrameworkMethodOptionsPart1 & FrameworkMethodOptionsPart2<T>
```

Comment: Hey Shannon. It was a nice try, but I added more examples that show cases where it doesn't work. I updated the question.